# Boolean operation doesn't work even with perfect normals and vertices

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'd like to apply the boolean operator to subtract the rod-like structure (highlighted) from the dish antenna. Ideally, the bottom of the rods should make a hole on the dish, but it doesn't work in that way. The normal vectors direction look fine. I also merged close vertices to avoid duplicated vertices. What would be a possible reason for the failure?

[image]

[image: Model that I want to apply boolean opeeration on]

Comment: In the Boolean modifier, under Solver Options, enable Hole Tolerant, or use the Fast option instead of Exact. That said it won't give good topology

Comment: @moonboots, thank you for your comment. I tried both options, but it did not change the result.

Comment: Q&D way: (1) Select each object (one at a time) and in *Edit Mode*, go to *Mesh/Separate/By Loose Parts* ("3d" will make 5 parts and "top" will make 13 parts); (2) Add 6 Boolean modifiers to the parabola from "3d"; (3) Select one pole after the other as intersecting object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 3d_antenna to become 3d_antenna minus th space occupied by top_antenna.  But when we do that, we see that it doesn't act as you anticipated:

[image]

There are a few requirements for a boolean to work well.  There are tricks that Blender does to try to make it work okay even when it doesn't work well, but those are just tricks-- it's a computer "helping" you model, which is a lot like a toddler helping you build a house.

When does it work well?  1) When both meshes are manifold-- ie, watertight.  2) When neither mesh has any self-intersection.  3) When there are no coincident faces-- places where overlapping faces exist in the same plane.

1. Are these meshes watertight?  No.

[image]

Neither mesh is watertight.  Both have non-manifold elements.

2. Do these meshes self intersect?  Yes.

[image]

The objects are made up of multiple mesh islands, which intersect with each other.  While I'm looking only at 3d_antenna here, the other mesh self-intersects as well:

[image]

3. Do these meshes have coincident faces?  I don't think they do, I only offered that for completeness.  But-- I didn't look that close.

Those three things are necessary for a boolean operation to figure out, what is inside, and what is outside?  With self-intersection, parts are inside *and* outside at the same time.  With non-manifold geometry, there is no particular inside or outside.  And with coincident faces, it just can't decide, it's right *there*, so is that inside or outside?  It's right exactly at the border where inside becomes outside.

How can we fix the self intersection we see here?  By boolean unioning mesh islands:

[image]

How can we fix the fact that some mesh elements are not manifold?  By excluding those from our booleans by separating them out to different objects:

[image]

If we had a problem with coincident faces, how could we solve it?  By moving something very, very slightly.

And when I fix some subset of these, I see that a boolean difference works fine:

[image]

Well, as fine as a boolean will ever work on a smooth shaded mesh without retopo, which isn't very much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent answer! My problem has been resolved!